# i want sales report in blocks

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table `sales_person` and `sales`

sales_person

```
id|sales person|email|username|password|
```

sales

```
id|company name|contact person|email|phone|sold by|booth number|date|
```

i want the sales report of the each sales persons in blocks how can i do this

```
SELECT `company_name`, `contact_person`, `phone_number`, `booth_number` 
   FROM `registration` 
   WHERE `sold_by` = '$username'";
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocks?

Comment: means all sales person report in one page one after one

Comment: Please give an example of what you tried, how you want to be assisted and what you want to achieve, whats a block??, or what do you mean by sales report, how and what content would you want in the table to be displayed

Comment: i have floor plan in with number of booths i have 4 sales person who's booked the booth, and i m admin and i want to see the report of the sales according to sales person means how many booth booked by the sales person

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, this is an example what you want:

```
<?php

    $server = "yourserver";
    $user = "youruser";
    $pass = "yourpass";
    $db = "dbname";

    $conexion=mysql_connect ($server, $user, $pass) or die ('problems with conexion:' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ($db, $conexion);

    $sql ="SELECT company_name, contact_person, phone_number, booth_number FROM registration WHERE sold_by = $username;" 
    $table = mysql_query($sql, $conexion) or die ("error... <br><b>" . mysql_error()."</b>");

    $finds = mysql_num_rows($table);
    echo "Persons: ".$finds."<br>;

    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($table)) {
       echo $r['company_name', 'company_name', 'contact_person, 'phone_number', 'booth_number']; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a particular page of a report you would do something like this :

```
SELECT `company_name`, `contact_person`, `phone_number`, `booth_number` 
   FROM `registration` 
   WHERE `sold_by` = '$username' limit '$pageSize' * '$pageNumber', '$pageSize'";
```

where pageSize is the number of rows you want to get from the db and pageNumber specifies which page you want.

You should put an "order by" clause so that your entries are ordered by some user defined attribute rather than the order of entry into the db.

Comment: i have floor plan in with number of booths i have 4 sales person who's booked the booth, and i m admin and i want to see the report of the sales according to sales person means how many booth booked by the sales person

Comment: this looks like a completely different question. you can use `group by sold_by` to get aggregated data.